# Nlog filter when condition with equals not working

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I have to pass the variable value from my startup class

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["environment"] = "Development";
```

I have added below filter in my nlog.config file

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile">
        <filters>
            <when condition="equals('${var:environment}', 'Development')" action="Ignore" />                
        </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

Even though I pass the value as Development, the message is still getting logged instead of ignore.

However, when I hardcoded the value it's working

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have found a [bug in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4835), but it should work if you do this (Will also be faster):

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile">
        <filters defaultAction='log'>
            <when condition="'${var:environment}' == 'Development'" action="Ignore" />                
        </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

Notice you can also use Layout in `minLevel`. Ex. `minLevel="${var:EnvironmentMinLevel:whenEmpty=Error}"`, which is much faster than `<filters>`.

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["EnvironmentMinLevel"] = "Off";
NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration